# Swaping two rows of 2 dimensional character array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, swap

I have a 2D character array, I want to swap two rows of this array.
I can think of this function.

```
char str[5][5];
swap(str[i],str[j]);
void swap(char * p, char *q) {
    char *temp;
    temp = p;
    p = q;
    q = temp;
}
```

This function does not work.
I also came up with this,

```
char ** temp1;
char ** temp2;
temp1 = &str[i];
temp2 = &str[j];
*temp1 = str[j];
*temp2 = str[i];
```

This does not work either, please suggest me a proper way to do this task.

Comment: Send in a length to the `swap` function, and add a loop in it, swapping each element.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap( char *s1,  char *s2, size_t n  )
{
    char t[n];

    strcpy( t, s1 );
    strcpy( s1, s2 );
    strcpy( s2, t );
}

#define N   5

int main(void) 
{
    char s[N][N] =
    {
        "Cat",
        "Dog",
        "Cow",
        "Bird",
        "Goat"
    };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) puts( s[i] );

    puts( "" );

    swap( s[0], s[3], N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) puts( s[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Cat
Dog
Cow
Bird
Goat

Bird
Dog
Cow
Cat
Goat
```

Take into account that you can use also standard function `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`.

The other approach is to use standard function `memcpy` that to copy exactly N characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
void swap( char * ary, int idx1, int idx2, int rowlen )
{
    for ( int x=0; x<rowlen; x++ )
    {
        temp = ary[idx1][x];
        ary[idx1][x] = ary[idx2][x];
        ary[idx2][x] = temp;
    }
}

#define ROWLEN 5
void main( void )
{
    char str[5][ROWLEN];
    swap( str, 2, 4, ROWLEN );  // swap rows 2 and 4
}
```

I didn't compile this so there might be syntax errors, but this should convey the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to swap every elements of the two rows :

```
void swapRows(char* row1, char* row2, size_t rowlen)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<rowlen; ++i)
    {
        char tmp = row1[i];
        row1[i] = row2[i];
        row2[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Here we have a function that takes a pointer to two rows of your array, the length of a row, and that runs a very simple loop to swap every elements of those rows. Here is how you would use it :

```
int main()
{
    char str[2][2] = {{'1','2'},{'3','4'}};

    swapRows(&str[0][0], &str[1][0], 2);

    // str now contains {'3','4'},{'2','1'}
}
```

What you seem to have tried is to swap the pointers to the rows instead of physically moving the content of the rows. That can't work. Pointers only allow you to find your data, but moving them around doesn't actually modify that data. Now, if you had a `char**` array this idea would work, but in the case of a contiguous 2D `char[][]` array you have to move things physically.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a contiguous 2D array, not an array of pointers, one should use [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html) to copy five-element subarrays, like this:

```
void swap(char *p, char *q) {
    char temp[5];
    memcpy(temp, p, sizeof(temp));
    memcpy(p, q, sizeof(temp));
    memcpy(q, temp, sizeof(temp));
}
```

The idea is to make an array buffer sufficient to hold one "row", copy the first row into it, and then do the swap the usual way (i.e. with an assignment of a temporary variable).

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/GYEEHR)